# pecl installs for previous php version

Tags: php, pear, apc, pecl, osx-mavericks

I've upgraded my MacBook to Mavericks and ruined my development environment. The problem I have right now is that my pear/pecl still tries to install for my previous (5.3) version of PHP instead of version 5.4.

PHP version:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2013 02:03:38) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Pear

```
$ pear version
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.4.17
Zend Engine Version: 2.4.0
Running on: Darwin MBP-retina.local 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

If I install apc with

```
$ sudo pecl install apc
downloading APC-3.1.13.tgz ...
Starting to download APC-3.1.13.tgz (171,591 bytes)
.....................................done: 171,591 bytes
55 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
...
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.26/include/php/ext/apc/apc_serializer.h'
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.26/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/APC-3.1.13
Extension apc enabled in php.ini
```

And enable the apc module in my php.ini php -v changes to this:

```
$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/apc.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/apc.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2013 02:03:38) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

So pecl installs my apc extension in `/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.26/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626` and php expects it in `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/`.

Simply making a symlink gives the following error:

```
$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apc: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2013 02:03:38) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

So that's not a solution.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I really don't have a clue what is going on here.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple. I had to make modifications to my pecl config. It turned out that these two command did the trick:

```
sudo pear config-set php_ini /etc/php.ini
sudo pecl config-set bin_dir /usr/bin/
```

pecl used the wrong phpize. There were two versions of the phpize. The same counts for my php.ini file.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you.  I have been fighting this issue for 12 hours and couldn't figure out why pecl wouldn't build for PHP 5.5.  Running those two commands fixed it.  You literally saved my ass.

Answer (score 45):

In my case, I was attempting to install Gearman.

pecl install gearman would install it incorrectly.

`php -i` would show:

```
PHP Extension => 20100525
```

Yet pecl would install using:

```
PHP Api Version:         20090626
```

After changing my config settings to use:

**First Fix**

```
sudo pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php.ini
sudo pecl config-set php_bin /usr/bin/php5
```

I noticed that I would still get

> WARNING: php_bin /usr/bin/php5 appears to have a suffix 5, but config
>   variable php_suffix does not match

You can resolve this by using the config setting:

**Additional Fix**

```
sudo pear config-set php_suffix 5
```

---

## Why was this a problem?

For me, I got into this problem because I added a custom PPA and reinstalled PHP. This meant that my previous install of php5-dev was out of sync.

You if you ever get into the same situation, you might just want to run..

```
apt-get remove php5-dev
pecl uninstall <extensionname>
apt-get install php5-dev
apt-get remove php5-pear
apt-get install php5-pear
pecl install <extensionname>
```

Alternatively, you can download the source and run phpize.

Comment: Thanks - removing and re-installing php5-dev did the trick for me. Phew.

Comment: this answer helped me a lot to solve bit different problem

Comment: I don't get the Mac hype.  Why can't you just download a file and plop it in there??

Comment: I also had to run `sudo pear config-set php_ini /etc/php.ini` -- pecl apparently was using pear's config invisibly.

Comment: You saved my life
`sudo pear config-set php_suffix 7.3` 
This is best solution for me.

Comment: Honestly, I only wrote this answer for myself to act as a wiki for when I need to reinstall gearman on an old legacy application. I think I wasted a day on this issue 6 years ago.. (but it feels like yesterday). I doubt this fix even works on any new php version now, w still run gearman oni legacy stuff but moved to amqp rabbitmq for most messaging.

Comment: The solution should mention the fix for multiple versions of phpize as @Tobi G. explained in his post. Anyway that resolved my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

None of the other answers (as yet) seem to address having multiple "co-installable" PHP versions while wanting to build a given extension for all installed PHP versions.

To illustrate the scenario in which I find myself (I'm using the Ondrej Surý PHP PPAs for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS):

```
root@localhost:~# ls -lah /usr/bin/*php*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     11K Apr 19 12:50 dh_php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    3.1K Apr  5  2016 dh_phpcomposer
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    5.4K Apr  5  2016 dh_phppear
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      21 Jul 24 00:44 php -> /etc/alternatives/php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4.3M Jul  6 10:04 php5.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4.3M Jul  6 10:04 php7.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4.4M Aug  4 14:22 php7.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      28 Jul 24 00:44 php-config -> /etc/alternatives/php-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4.3K Jul  6 10:03 php-config5.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4.1K Jul  6 10:03 php-config7.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4.1K Aug  4 14:21 php-config7.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      24 Jul 24 00:44 phpize -> /etc/alternatives/phpize
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4.7K Jul  6 10:03 phpize5.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4.6K Jul  6 10:03 phpize7.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4.6K Aug  4 14:21 phpize7.1
```

`pecl install extension-name` does the job for PHP 7.1, but not the others.

The other anwsers indicate that while it's possible to uninstall/reinstall `php*-dev`, I'd much rather not, given the intentional, co-installed PHP versions on the system.

One solution is to build the extension for each version present on the system.

This snippet demonstrates building with PHP 5.6, but I've done the same for 7.0 and 7.1 and the steps are the same.

This example demonstrates cloning the extension from a Git repository, but one may use any source directory.

(`#` indicates that you must be root or use `sudo`)

```
# apt-get install php-dev

# cd ~

# git clone https://github.com/vendor/extension-name

# cd ./extension-name

# phpize5.6

# ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config5.6

# make clean

# make

# make install

# ln -s /etc/php/5.6/mods-available/extension-name.ini /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-extension-name.ini

# service php5.6-fpm reload
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a way to switch PHP version on Ubuntu:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

and optionally:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config5.6
```

Source: https://superuser.com/a/1100911/371795

Answer (score 6):

Better to reinstall phpize extensions as it will be used by PECL and not make hacks.

Do next (php 5.5 => php 5.6 example) :

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-dev
sudo apt-get install php5.6-dev
```

(you can change 5.6 to version you need)

Then:

```
sudo pecl install extensionname
```

Comment: This is actually the correct way to fix this instead of messing up the configuration which more often than not leads to more problems.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16.04, when using *ppa:ondrej/php* (and probably other alternatives), in order to install pecl/php extensions for php 5.6, you have to do the following:

```
pecl config-set ext_dir /usr/lib/php/20131226
pecl config-set php_bin /usr/bin/php5.6
pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
pear config-set ext_dir /usr/lib/php/20131226
pear config-set php_bin /usr/bin/php5.6
pear config-set php_ini /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
update-alternatives --config php #select php 5.6
update-alternatives --config php-config #select php 5.6
update-alternatives --config phpize #select php 5.6
```

Next you can use pecl as usual:

```
pecl install raphf-1.1.2
```

> downloading raphf-1.1.2.tgz ...
>   Starting to download raphf-1.1.2.tgz (15,915 bytes)
>   ......done: 15,915 bytes
>   8 source files, building
>
> running: phpize
>
> Configuring for:
>
> PHP Api Version:         20131106
>
> Zend Module Api No:      20131226
>
> Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
>
> ...
>
> install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/raphf-1.1.2
>
> Extension raphf enabled in php.ini

I noticed that, when no extension are enabled in php.ini, pecl add the line `extension="xxx.so"` at the beginning of the php.ini, so I usually move it at the end of the file, manually, and after it's ok for the next extensions.

**Depending of what you have on your system, it may be necessary to rollback your changes after install, especially for the default php version to use, with update-alternatives**

Answer (score 2):

Encountered similar problem recently.

(Debian, PHP 7.3 just installed, was using PHP 7.2)

If anybody tried the highest voted answer but still not working.
Here are the steps to debug:

- Remove all other php versions, especially the dev package (php7.2-dev in my case)
- install the dev package for the current version (php7.3-dev)

And basically that's it.

Reason:

PECL requires phpize which is part of php-dev package.
If phpize for the current version is not found, if will look for the previous version, which resulting a older PHP API number