# PHP unable to load dynamic library (mongo.so)

Tags: php, mongodb

i'm trying to use rockmongo. After installation, i'm unable to use it. It says "**To make things right, you must install php_mongo module. Here for installation documents on PHP.net.**"

i have already installed mongoDB driver extension via `sudo pecl install mongo`.

`locate mongo` shows `/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mongo.so`

However, `php -v` shows few warnings (which i think is related to mongo)

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ']' in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mongodb.ini on line 3
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/mongo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.28-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: May  5 2014 09:39:26) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

i opened `/usr/lib/php5/` and found out that there are another directory(**20090626+lfs**) which contains mongo.so.

i tried various online tutorial, but nothing helped.

**Edit**: Here's my mongodb.ini

```
;----- start -----
extension=mongo.so
\[mongo\]
; If the driver should reconnect to mongo
mongo.auto_reconnect = true
; Whether to allow persistent connections
mongo.allow_persistent = On
; Maximum number of persistent connections (-1 means unlimited)
mongo.max_persistent = -1
; Maximum number of links (persistent and non-persistent, -1 means unlimited)
mongo.max_connections = -1
; Default host for mongo connection
mongo.default_host = www.example.com
; Default port for mongo database
mongo.default_port = 42
; When saving files to the database, size of chunks to split them into
mongo.chunk_size = 1024
; Specify an alternate character to $ to use for special db functions ($set, $push, $exists, etc.)

mongo.cmd = "$"
;----- end -----
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongo.so: > undefined symbol: php\_json\_encode in Unknown on line 0. After installation mongo driver for php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952994/mongo-so-undefined-symbol-php-json-encode-in-unknown-on-line-0-after-instal)

Comment: i have already tried the solutions mentioned there. Didn't help.

Comment: Edit your question to include your mongodb.ini file. Hint: `expecting ']' in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mongodb.ini on line 3`

Comment: Where can I find this mongodb.ini file??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved this problem using the 1.1.9 version of mongodb driver for **php 5**. First uninstall the current version of mongodb and then install the 1.1.9 version:

```
sudo pecl uninstall mongodb
sudo pecl install mongodb-1.1.9
composer update
```

Comment: Is this still uptodate?

Comment: For me version 1.1.9 don't work. But I check latest version at https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb  (it was 1.4.4) and install it. All work fine.

Comment: In fact, I installed the latest mongodb driver for php 7.2 and it worked fine. But for **php 5** version (this post) I recommend using the mongodb driver v1.1.9. For the current version it is only necessary to execute the command: `sudo pecl install mongodb`

Answer (score 9):

My php version is 7.0, but it should work version 5.x  too.

If you have this in the file `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mongo.ini`

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

Comment that line. After that restart php and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

For me this works well

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mongodb
```

Change the '7.2' for your php version

Answer (score 1):

Add the full path to your mongo.so extension in `mongodb.ini`:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mongo.so
```

Also the `[mongo]` should be written exactly like that NOT `\[mongo\]`.

Don't forget to reload/restart your web server to load the new configuration.

You can check that everything is ok with:

```
php -i | grep mongo
```

Comment: i edited `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and changed `extension=mongo` to `extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mongo.so`. Also, changed `\[mongo\]` to `[mongo]` in `etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mongodb.ini`. Restarted apache. Still same error

Comment: You changed the extension=mongo in `php.ini` but the error is in `mongodb.ini`. Remove the `extension=..` line from php.ini and change it in the `mongodb.ini` file.

Comment: Same error. `php -v` shows 

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: You had two errors: the one with invalid syntax and the one with wrong path to mongo.so file. What's your error now?

Comment: both errors are gone now. But still i'm unable to open `localhost/rockmongo`. It says `To make things right, you must install php_mongo module. Here for installation documents on PHP.net.Also, i typed `php-v` again on terminal and it shows the above mentioned warning(unable to initialize module)

Comment: Then go step by step. First, delete the mongodb.ini file and check with php -v that you don't have any errors. If no errors are showing, try to add mongodb.ini with only `extension` part.

Comment: After, deleting `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mongodb.ini`, `php -v` doesn't show any errors. i created `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mongodb.ini` and included `extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mongo.so`. Now same error. `These options need to match`

Comment: That's the error you get when you're trying to load older modules with a newer version of php. Try to upgrade your mongo module and change the path to the new version.

Comment: i tried `sudo pecl uninstall mongo` and then `sudo pecl install mongo`. Restarted Apache. Still `These options need to match`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561722/pecl-installs-for-previous-php-version

Answer (score 0):

After OS update, I had a similar error while running any PHP CLI, simply running "php -v" produced the error:

PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/mongodb.so'

I checked the folder, I found the file '/usr/lib/php/20131226/mongodb.so' existed. So, I simply commented on the line "extension=mongo.so" in '/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini' file. It fixed my issue.

When checked mongo --version, it was working fine.