# Laravel Homestead Mongo install causing PHP error undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, homestead

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so:
>   undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0

After installing MongoDB I'm now get this error whenever I run any php command from terminal:

> php artisan
>
> php -v

I have searched for 2 days now. I have seen these:

[PHP unable to load dynamic library (mongo.so)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030255/php-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-mongo-so)

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/issues/126

and I'm pretty sure any other solution that comes up from google this error. They all seem to be fixes for php5 and ain't working for me.

I have added extension=mongodb.so to ini files.

I have destroyed VM and started fresh 100 times.

I'm running:
Vagrant 1.8.5
Laravel Installer version 1.3.3

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ php -v 

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0 PHP
7.0.13-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.13-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with blackfire v1.14.1~linux-x64-non_zts70, https://blackfire.io, by Blackfireio Inc.
```

Mongo is installed and running fine:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.0
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-12-05T15:32:01.158+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2016-12-05T15:32:01.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-12-05T15:32:01.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2016-12-05T15:32:01.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2016-12-05T15:32:01.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-12-05T15:32:01.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-12-05T15:32:01.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-12-05T15:32:01.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-12-05T15:32:01.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-12-05T15:32:01.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-12-05T15:32:01.205+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-12-05T15:32:01.205+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>
```

But I can't stop this php error for nothing in the world!!!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I haven't found a solution yet, but the problem might be related to the 1.1.0 release from yesterday: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/releases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the problem is here that mongodb.so depends on json.so. The solution is to load mongodb.so after json.so.

I guess you are using the custom Mongo script for Homestead. The script outputs the mongodb.so module in php.ini file with the result that mongodb.so is loaded first.
You should create a mongodb.ini file where mongodb.so is loaded.

Create the .ini-file: /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mongodb.ini with content:

```
; configuration for php mongo module
; priority=30
extension=mongodb.so
```

Give it priority 30, since json gets 20 (in my settings) to be sure it is loaded afterwards.

Create a softlink of the ini-file to /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d to make it available for the webserver.

```
ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mongodb.ini 30-mongodb.ini
```

Reload webserver and php-fpm.

```
sudo service [your webserver] restart && sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

You are done! You can config the cli-version the same way

Comment: This works great for php 7.1 too, just swap out 7.0 to 7.1 in the paths.

Comment: Works like a charm! :D I have been searching the whole morning about a solution! Thanks! 
PS.: I didn't configure the cli-version. Is it necessary?

Comment: Cli-version is only necessary if you're using packages that use cli (in background). For instance, the moloquent (mongo for Laravel) requires cli when you install it via composer.

Comment: Does not work. Still getting the same error on CLI for php 7.1. Have restarted php7.1-fpm and nginx

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I solved it by reverting to an older PECL mongodb version (1.1.9). There was an update to [version 1.2.0 on November 29th](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb), which is why the mongo-php-library also got updated to [version 1.1.0](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/releases).

Here is what I did:

```
sudo pecl uninstall mongodb
sudo pecl install mongodb-1.1.9
composer update
```

The pecl commands will show the same warning, but the installation was successfully completed.

I hope that the mongo-php-library will be fixed soon, so we're not stuck using an older PECL extension.

Comment: Chris is right.  Make sure it is loaded after json extension

Comment: Yep, I saw that, it's a much better solution.