# PHP 7: MongoDB Driver issue

Tags: php, mongodb, apache

I just got errors when I try to install MongoDB PHP Library:

```
$ composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0"

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0
```

When I execute `phpinfo()` I can see the following:

```
mongodb

mongodb support enabled
mongodb version 1.2.1
mongodb stability   stable
libmongoc version   1.5.0
libbson version 1.5.0
```

When I execute locate mongodb.so here's where my mongodb.so file is:

```
/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so
```

As I can notice, this is the path where `20-mongodb.ini` file is:

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d
```

Also, `sudo pecl mongodb install` returns the following:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0
```

`sudo pecl info mongodb` returns:

```
About pecl.php.net/mongodb-1.2.1
================================
Release Type          PECL-style PHP extension (source code)
Name                  mongodb
Channel               pecl.php.net
Summary               MongoDB driver for PHP
Description           The purpose of this driver is to provide
                      exceptionally thin glue between MongoDB
                      and PHP, implementing only fundemental and
                      performance-critical components
                      necessary to build a fully-functional MongoDB
                      driver.
Maintainers           Hannes Magnusson <bjori@php.net> (lead)
                      Jeremy Mikola <jmikola@php.net> (lead)
                      Derick Rethans <derick@php.net> (lead)
Release Date          2016-12-07 18:25:03
Release Version       1.2.1 (stable)
API Version           1.2.1 (stable)
License               Apache License
                      (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)
Release Notes         ** Bug
                          * [PHPC-848] - Fix BSON encoding of
                      immutable arrays and documents with circular
                      references
Required Dependencies PHP version 5.4.0-7.99.99
                      PEAR installer version 1.4.8 or newer
package.xml version   2.0
Last Modified         2016-12-09 00:28
Previous Installed    1.2.0
Version
```

I searched on Google for a few hours, but still nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are good answers.
Here's what I did to install mongo in php7.1. I am using ubuntu16.04 64bit:

```
sudo aptitude install -y php7.1-dev pkg-config
sudo -H pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
sudo aptitude install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libsslcommon2-dev
sudo pecl install mongodb
echo 'extension=mongodb.so' | sudo tee /etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d/30-mongodb.ini
echo 'extension=mongodb.so' | sudo tee /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/30-mongodb.ini
sudo systemctl restart php7.1-fpm.service
```

It it all for nginx. If you are using apache, please add:

```
echo 'extension=mongodb.so' | sudo tee /etc/php/7.1/apache2/conf.d/30-mongodb.ini
```

And one more. If you continue to have an error when working with mongo. Something like that:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/mongodb.so' - libssl.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Do not despair, run the following commands:

```
sudo pecl uninstall mongodb
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Answer (score 4):

First type this command `/usr/bin/php-config` to see where the extension directory is.
You will see something like this `--extension-dir     [/usr/lib/php/20131226]`
Than `ls` in that folder see if the `mongo.so` is there , if not put it there.
Type `whereis php` to locate the php you are using in `CLI` 
Edit the php.ini for the CLI and add the `extension=mongo.so`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My extension directory is here: ```/usr/lib/php/20151012``` and ```mongodb.so``` is there (not ```mongo.so``` because that's deprecated). Anyway, here's loaded configuration file: ```/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini``` with additional ini files in the following directory  ```/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d``` where ```20-mongodb.ini``` file is.

Comment: Hi, you have to add the `extension=mongodb.so` inside the `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` and it should work.

Comment: thank you. The whole day I'm solving this issue but still nothing. When I type ```php --ini``` 

I simply get the following error: ```PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: php_json_serializable_ce in Unknown on line 0``` 
Anyway, this might be a solution: https://derickrethans.nl/undefined-symbol.html but still nothing.

Comment: This is a different error now i think, you can refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979377/laravel-homestead-mongo-install-causing-php-error-undefined-symbol-php-json-ser)

Answer (score 0):

Use the 1.1.9 mongodb version:

```
sudo pecl uninstall mongodb
sudo pecl install mongodb-1.1.9
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

I did as @Andrinux and @J.C. Gras suggestions and I got an error `phpize not found`.

So I did research and found this [How to install and run phpize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108937/how-to-install-and-run-phpize). This is because `php-dev` was not installed on my system, so I did install it.

In the sequence, I did:

```
// Ubuntu 20.04.3
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install php-dev
$ sudo pecl install mongodb (at the time, it installed mongodb-1.10.0)
```

If you see this message, the extension has successfully installed

```
Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootDvmP4U/install-mongodb-1.10.0" install
Installing shared extensions:     /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootDvmP4U/install-mongodb-1.10.0/usr/lib/php/20200930/
running: find "/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootDvmP4U/install-mongodb-1.10.0" | xargs ls -dils
52067    4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Sep 28 16:18 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootDvmP4U/install-mongodb-1.10.0
52629    4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Sep 28 16:18 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootDvmP4U/install-mongodb-1.10.0/usr
52630    4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Sep 28 16:18 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootDvmP4U/install-mongodb-1.10.0/usr/lib
52631    4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Sep 28 16:18 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootDvmP4U/install-mongodb-1.10.0/usr/lib/php
52632    4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Sep 28 16:18 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootDvmP4U/install-mongodb-1.10.0/usr/lib/php/20200930
52627 8708 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8916120 Sep 28 16:18 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootDvmP4U/install-mongodb-1.10.0/usr/lib/php/20200930/mongodb.so

Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20200930/mongodb.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongodb-1.10.0
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=mongodb.so" to php.ini
```

> Don't forget to restart PHP-FPM and APACHE server