# How do I fix "PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb' "

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am trying to install and set up mongodb with a laravel application for the first time. I read that I have to install the extension and libraries but after I do that I get the above error when I try to execute a php command in the terminal.

I am running windows 10 x64 and PHP 7.3.1.

First of all I installed the mongodb from the official mongodb site

I got the latest mongodb dll from https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.6.0/windows

I extracted the dll into the c:/xampp/php/ext folder according to the instructions and restarted the server.

I also included the `extension = php_mongodb.dll` in the php.ini file

This is what I get...

[image]

I found a similar post on here  [PHP unable to load dynamic library (mongo.so)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030255/php-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-mongo-so) that could have solved my problem but that solution is for users on mac and I am on windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP unable to load dynamic library (mongo.so)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030255/php-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-mongo-so)

Comment: I think that's for the mac os but I'm on windows

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075616/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-mongo-dll Its for windows.

Comment: Which dll did you download?

Comment: yeah so turns out I was running x86 of xampp and was trying to use x64 mongodb dll but I got the x86 dll and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here. Turns out my xampp version was x86 and so x64 version of the dll would obviously not work... Solution was to just use x86 version of the dll instead.